# Git top level dir Name

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I am trying to retrieve the top level dir name but the `$GIT` var is returning empty? this is for git integration in the terminal.

```
function root_func() {
    GIT="git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree"
    if [[ $GIT =~ "True" ]]; then
    git rev-parse --show-toplevel | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $(NF-0)}'
    fi  }
```

Comment: I am aware of True/true. I am getting no difference with either for some reason. From the term it just returns empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GIT="git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree"
```

That's just setting `GIT` to a string. I think you actually want

```
GIT=$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree)
```

You can also do this pretty easily as a one-liner:

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1 && basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```